# Make generic program - build execution graph (tree) and execute it in ansi C engine?

Tags: c, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to implement PLC like HW that would be able to be programmed with some universal programming language (can be ANSI C for a start).

I'd like to program HW in several steps :

- write generic program in txt file (can be subset of ANSI C for a
  start)
- parse that txt file and build some sort of execution graph to
  be sent to ansi c engine on embedded HW
- have ansi c engine that can execute "execution graph" over and over...

I've found pretty similar and interesting project here: 
http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/DDJ/1989/8908/8908d/8908d.htm

but this is interpreter and parses program as a text for each step and is getting pretty slow and not space friendly. What I would like to change in this story is to parse C program in execution structure (AST?) once and then just execute it with ansi c engine on embedded HW.

I'm pretty sure that something similar is already done and shared. Please help me with starting points, advice or any other opinion...

Thanks in advance,

regards,

Bulek.

Comment: This is just too broad (general) to be answerable. Maybe just try to start and when you run into a **specific** problem, ask that.

Comment: ok, thanks for response - will try to be more specific: I have an ansi c program that would be able to execute another snippet of ansi c code written in some sort of descriptive data structure...

Comment: Check out "cint", a C interpreter.  I suspect it does everything you want.